# .NET 5.0 and 6.0, background service not stopping like samples from MS

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-6.0

In short I'm building a TCP server for a simple DB process.  I looked at the MS samples for background service specifically the App.WorkerService.

So far so good, can run the service and it only starts the TCP server once per app instance.

Now I want to have the service stopped when a user, in the command window it is running, hits the [ESC]ape key on the keyboard.

Here is the Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace PostDataService
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
              services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
  }
}
```

Here is the Worker class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WatsonTcp;

namespace PostDataService
{
  public class Worker : BackgroundService
  {
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private int _serverPort = 1701;
    private static WatsonTcpServer _Server;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
      _Server = new(null, _serverPort);
      _Server.Events.ClientConnected += ClientConnected;
      _Server.Events.ClientDisconnected += ClientDisconnected;
      _Server.Events.MessageReceived += MsgReceived;
      _Server.Start();
    }

    private void MsgReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Got Msg");
    }

    private void ClientDisconnected(object sender, DisconnectionEventArgs args)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ClientConnected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs args)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
      while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time} {threadid}", DateTimeOffset.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId );

        await Task.Delay(500, stoppingToken);
      }
      _Server.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

So how would I get the stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested set to true?

Comment: It is Ctrl+C  not Esc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut to stop console application is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> not <kbd>Esc</kbd>. If you still want <kbd>Esc</kbd> to be working you can do something like this:

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

var hostTask = host.RunAsync();

// listen for Esc 
_ = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo key;
    do
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey();
    }
    while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    await host.StopAsync();
});

await hostTask;
```

Also I recommend adding something like this in your `Worker`:

```
public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{ 
    _logger.LogInformation("stopping server");
    _Server.Stop();
    return Task.CompletedTask;  
}
```

Comment: This should be voted as answer.

Comment: I like the StopAsync handler.

Comment: The suggestion, is giving an error the return type of an async method must be void, task, task<t>... changed IHostbuilder to void, now just runs straight through and stops, so I must be missing something here.

Comment: @Larry not sure what have you done but try something like [this](https://pastebin.com/Zvh5kJU4). Or replace your program file with my answer completely - it is using [top level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements).

Comment: Interesting, VS2022 complains about Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.  And thats a copy and paste of your code.   Thanks much though appreciate the effort.

Comment: @Larry check language version selected for project. Or copy the `Main` from the first link in my previous comment.

Comment: IMHO instead of `host.RunAsync`, which is just (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.cs#L60) you should start / stop the host yourself. That way you don't need to run a separate task.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman;  You mention dropping the async, I admit I'm a bit green in the .net 6 world.  I want the app to run all day so as to process requests and when a new user connects I want it to be running on it's own thread.  This is a server doing DB work and multiple PCs will connect to this.

Comment: I mean that you can `await host.StartAsync()` which will block until every `IHostedService` has started, then continue with any other code you wish to run within `Main`. Such as waiting for specific content from `Console.In`. Then `Services.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>().StopApplication(); await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();`, as per the github link above.